# What does this memory address contain?

Tags: c, apache, gdb

I started Apache http server (version 2.4.12) in a gdb session. I am stepping through the code in the request.c module and I am printing out the contents of variables

This is the code

```
1546 AP_DECLARE(int) ap_file_walk(request_rec *r)
1547 {
1548     ap_conf_vector_t *now_merged = NULL;
1549     core_dir_config *dconf = ap_get_core_module_config(r->per_dir_config);
1550     ap_conf_vector_t **sec_ent = NULL;
1551     int num_sec = 0;
```

This is the output of *r that I am interested in:

```
  used_path_info = 2, 
  eos_sent = 0, 
  per_dir_config = 0x7fffe4251028, 
  request_config = 0x7fffe4258370, 
  log = 0x7ffff7fc1288, 
  log_id = 0x0,
```

And this is what I get when I examine per_dir_config

```
(gdb) print 0x7fffe4251028
$99 = 140737021022248
(gdb) x/s 0x7fffe4251028
0x7fffe4251028:  "\370\022%\344\377\177"
(gdb)
```

Would someone have time to explain to me what  `"\370\022%\344\377\177"` is?

Comment: `r->per_dir_config` is a pointer to `ap_conf_vector_t` structure. The string you are getting is it's contents (partially, maybe).

Comment: It is a sequence of seven `char`s, `'\370'`, `'\022'`, `'%'`, `'\344'`, `'\377'`, `'\177'`, `'\0'` (the terminating null character being implicit).  GDB is presenting them to you mostly as octal escapes.  It's the best GDB can do: it knows nothing about data types when you access memory directly via an address.

Comment: Why don't you just use print r->per_dir_config?

Answer (score 0):

This string `"\370\022%\344\377\177"` is the beginning of the core_dir_config struct pointed by r->per_dir_config in octal form when characters are not printable. In hexadecimal you'll have:

```
\370 = 11 111 000 = f8
\022 = 00 010 010 = 12
% = (ascii value) = 25
\344 = 11 100 100 = e4
\377 = 11 111 111 = ff
\177 = 01 111 111 = 7f
```

According to the value of other pointers, I guess your computer has a little endian processor so you have to reverse byte order. The value is then:

```
0x7fffe42512f8
```

It is the value of the d field of the core_dir_config struct pointed by r->per_dir_config.
And since d is a char *, you can type `x/s 0x7fffe42512f8` to see the string.